# How to get symfony2 application accessed without the app_dev.php (e.g www.app.com)

Tags: php, symfony

I made my first app using symfony just now.

Everything went perfectly well except for a stupid little thing that I cannot figure out:

I cannot accees the app from say localhost/symfonyapp/, instead i have to type the complete uri like this localhost/symfonyapp/web/app_dev.php/show/5

I know it will be a piece of cake stuff, but I am really stuck at this for some time.

Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `http://localhost/symfonyapp/web/show/5`. If it does not work, what web server are you using?

Comment: [**Removing web and app.php / app_dev.php from URL**](http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=37197&p=123621)

Answer (score 0):

in first of all please try clear the cache by app/config cache:clear -e=prod or by removing everything from app/cache directory.

Kid regards, 
Piotr Pasich